# beautifulsoup - filter text of anchor tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following html content :

```
<a href="http://app_url1" >install app xyz</a>
<a href="http://app_url2" >install app xyz</a>
<a href="http://app_url3" >install app aaa</a>
<a href="http://app_url4">install app aaa</a>
```

I want to filter the anchor tag texts that end with a given regex pattern (like xyz here)?
I am looking to pass a regex pattern to findAll instead of extra iteration of all `anchor` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the beautifulSoup `text` parameter in `find_all` method.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """<a href="http://app_url1" >install app xyz</a>
<a href="http://app_url2" >install app xyz</a>
<a href="http://app_url3" >install app aaa</a>
<a href="http://app_url4">install app aaa</a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup.findAll("a", text=re.compile("xyz$")))
```

Output:

```
[<a href="http://app_url1">install app xyz</a>, <a href="http://app_url2">install app xyz</a>]
```

Comment: hi big bounty 
if  I have <a href="http://app_url1" ><img src="/path.jpg">install app xyz</a>
then this seems not finding the text eventhough it matches the regex pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Using lambda with `str.endswith`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div><a href="http://app_url1" >install app xyz</a>
<a href="http://app_url2" >install app xyz</a>
<a href="http://app_url3" >install app aaa</a>
<a href="http://app_url4">install app aaa</a></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all("a", text=lambda x: x is not None and x.endswith("xyz")))
# --> [<a href="http://app_url1">install app xyz</a>, <a href="http://app_url2">install app xyz</a>]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this to get anchor tag texts:

```
>>> html = """<a href="http://app_url1" >install app xyz</a>
... <a href="http://app_url2" >install app xyz</a>
... <a href="http://app_url3" >install app aaa</a>
... <a href="http://app_url4">install app aaa</a>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
>>> anchor_texts = []
>>> anchor_texts.append(soup.get_text())
>>> for i in anchor_texts:
...    print(i)
```

Output:

```
install app xyz
install app xyz
install app aaa
install app aaa
```